# How to get valid records in Type 2 SCD Table by Month?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a Type 2 SCD table that looks like this:

| valid_from | valid_to | some_id | some_value | __updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-15 |  | 3cac2 | 80028 | 2023-08-31 18:38:54.000 |
| 2023-08-08 | 2023-11-14 | 13d17 | 833f4 | 2023-08-31 19:24:43.000 |
| 2023-05-09 | 2023-08-08 | 13d17 | 833f4 | 2023-08-31 19:11:18.000 |
| 2023-11-14 |  | 13d17 | 833f4 | 2023-11-17 17:42:07.000 |
| 2022-11-15 | 2023-05-09 | 13d17 | 833f4 | 2023-08-31 18:38:54.000 |
| 2023-07-11 |  | c49f0 | acd1c | 2023-08-31 19:17:20.000 |
| 2023-07-11 |  | dcaa7 | 20258 | 2023-08-31 19:17:20.000 |
| 2022-11-15 | 2023-07-11 | dcaa7 | 20258 | 2023-08-31 18:38:54.000 |
| 2022-11-15 |  | f27f1 | c5bbb | 2023-08-31 18:38:54.000 |
| 2023-01-10 | 2023-02-14 | 7bd74 | 5a0e6 | 2023-08-31 18:50:12.000 |

How can I count the number of records that were **valid** in each `valid_from` date in the table, but not count the records that were invalidated *before* the given `valid_from` date?

I've tried:

```
select 
valid_from, 
sum(count(valid_from)) over(order by valid_from rows  unbounded preceding and current row ) as running_records_added,
sum(count(valid_to)) over( order by valid_from rows unbounded preceding and current row ) as running_records_removed,
running_records_added - running_records_removed
from some_scd_table
group by 1
order by 1;
```

But this seems to only count the number of *currently valid* records in each month, whereas I'm hoping to only count the records that were valid *up until* the given `valid_from` date.

I've also tried using an `inner join` on a table of dates

```
with dates as (

  select date_of_interest from some_dates_table

)

select 
date_of_interest.
count(*)
from dates
inner join some_scd_table 
  on some_scd_table.valid_from <= dates.date_of_interest
  and some_scd_table.valid_to > dates.date_of_interest
```

This gives the correct results, but it seems like there should be a more performant method than using an inequality join:

This seems like an easily solve-able problem, but I'm having some trouble figuring our the optimal way to query this data.

Comment: Add a table that shows desired output. You want to count valid records per each valid_from date then do a running sum on that count? Build aggregate SQL then reference that query in another that does running sum with unbounded method.